# What application can I use to block hosts with regex?

Tags: internet, web, hosts

Is there any tool/application that I can use to block hosts from all forms of connection from my computer? Currently I use `/etc/hosts` and place the absolute host like this:

```
127.0.0.1 unix.stackexchange.com
127.0.0.1 www.unix.stackexchange.com
```

But with regex it would be easier to something like this

```
127.0.0.1 .*stackexchange.*
```

Which would block everything with `stackexchange`in the url.

Comment: Do you want to block output or input only or both?

Comment: @slm Output i guess, or both.

Comment: Related: [Blocking Websites with /etc/hosts](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/127766/blocking-websites-with-etc-hosts/127769#127769) as well as this: [Block a certain URL?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/169218/block-a-certain-url/169234#169234)

Comment: Are you looking for something like [this](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2010/09/squid-control-internet-access/)? I see you could use regex with *squid*.

Comment: Using the post that @Ramesh provides above + [this one that shows how to setup transparent proxying w/ Squid](http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/linux-setup-transparent-proxy-squid-howto.html) is likely going to give you what you want.

Answer (score -1):

## Determine [ASN](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autonomous_System_%28Internet%29)

```
whois -h whois.radb.net `dig +short stackoverflow.com`
```

## Manage Traffic

```
for ip in `whois -h whois.radb.net '!gAS25791' | grep /`
do
    iptables -A -s $IP -j DROP
done
```

Answer (score -1):

As for hassle-free solutions, many use fail2ban: http://www.fail2ban.org/

Rules can be customised, see http://www.fail2ban.org/wiki/index.php/Commands

> `set <JAIL> addfailregex <REGEX>`